# MONO/ASP.NET Linux Hosts?

Tags: asp.net, mono, mod-mono

I was wondering if anyone knew of any webhosts that let you deploy asp.net applications to run under mono.

*edit*: Ideally, the host would require little to no configuration on my part to deploy an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick Google search turned up these:

1. [Ubiquity Hosting](http://www.ubiquityhosting.com//index.php?pid=shared-web-hosting-plans&cat=web-hosting)
2. [Grokthis](http://www.grokthis.net/Hosting/advanced/)

I've never personally used either of these, so procede with caution.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to go with a VPS. That way you can install mono at your lesiure.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to avoid the hassle of having to configure and manage the installation myself :-)

Answer (score 2):

I use Linode and they are great and cheap. I'm paying $19.99/month
Its a VPS though so you will have to setup an OS and install mono.

I know that goes against your point of having little or know config to do but I think the freedom it will give you will be worth it.

Derek

Answer (score 1):

In my (short) experience, there hasn't been any price difference between ASP.NET hosting and Linux based hosting, given the volume purchasing ability of Windows Server licenses. Thus, it would likely be easier to purchase Windows hosting for any ASP.net apps you have.

Unless of course you mainly want to play with Mono, in which case you could easily get a dedicated virtual box and install Mono on it.

Comment: I have to disagree regarding Linux/Windows hosting having similar pricing.  Windows hosting generally has less features if the price is comparable to a Linux hosting solution. In fact, over the past three years I've been slowly moving all my web projects to Linux solutions because of the pricing difference.

Comment: Interesting point, perhaps I haven't been utilizing all the features to notice the difference between the hosting plans. It seems that for most drop-in sites or things I've coded, they've been more than enough and similar if not the same price.

Answer (score 0):

The [Cloud Sites](http://www.mosso.com/cloud.jsp) offering from [Mosso (The Rackspace Cloud)](http://www.mosso.com/index.jsp) includes support for ASP.NET.

The configuration is extremely simple, and the hosting system supports Linux and Windows applications side-by-side.

Mosso [starts at $100/month](http://www.mosso.com/pricing.jsp).

I have used Mosso for a number of months, and I am fairly pleased with the service.

While some applications would definitely be better served by other solutions, I think Mosso is worth evaluating.

Answer (score 0):

This question was originally asked a long time ago, these days, the options are very expanded with https://www.asp.net/core

You can easily deploy asp.net core applications to [Azure](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/aspnet-core10-azure-web-apps), or any host that supports [Docker containers](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnet/).